# Linux subsystem ssh don`t see id_rsa.pub

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I used to have ssh connection to my server from bash console on Linux subsystem in Windows 10.

I reinstalled Windows and moved `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub` and `known_hosts` to exact the same folder where it was on previous system.

But now ssh dont see keys and ends up with error `Permission denied (publickey)`. 

But I still can connect using CMD with those keys so issue is not dependig on key file.

On previous system the ssh keys was stored on path: `C:\Users\My_Win10_User_Name\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\My_Linux_Subsystem_User_Name\.ssh` so I moved keys to this folder.

What steps should be taking to make ssh on Linux subsystem works again with my old keys?

Comment: I found solution for my case [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873234/user-ubuntu-does-not-have-access-to-home-ubuntu-ssh-on-ubuntu-server-16-04-1).

Answer (score 0):

ssh requires permissions to be correct.  Your ~/.ssh directory must be 0700, and the files inside must be 0600.  You also don't mention your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, which must contain your public key file (the contents of id_rsa.pub.)  That file, too, must be chmoded to 0600.

Comment: Console dont letting me further than `/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState` folder `rootfs` is `d---------`. When I try to chmod it says `chmod: cannot read directory 'rootfs/': Permission denied`